# How to turbo-boost at the start of a race?

Tags: wrecked-revenge-revisited

I know you can boost with `L2,R2,R2` (`LT,RT,RT`) but how can this be done at the start of the race? The top times on the leaderboards are using this technique but I can't figure it out. It looks like it randomly does the boost when you hold the right trigger when the countdown starts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they can consistently get the top times due to this randomness at the start. You have to luck out in that regard and then fallback on the built in boost mechanic.

Other than that you can try to use the 1 starting boost you have immediately *after* the race begins.

Also worth keeping in mind:

> Gameplay Tips:
>
> - Don' forget to boost ( to boost press LT, RT, RT in quick succession) this can mean the difference between gold and silver
> - Make sure you have boost when you attempt to use it or you will just slow down and lose time (you start each race with 1 boost and
>   acquire 1 more everytime you travel through a green checkpoint)
> - Make sure you take the racing line/shortest route, if you don't and keep zigzagging from side to side you will lose lots of time.
> - Keep an eye-out for short-cuts, some can take a few seconds off your time
> - Ignore the ghost cars, just because the gold ghost car took a short-cut doesn't mean you have to. Find a route that you are good at
>   and just keep trying, eventually you will get there.
> - On Ice Bridge and Arctic Outpost save your boosts for the sharp turns. As you are exiting the turns boost to get your car out of the
>   slide and back onto a racing line.
> - On Caravan races make sure as you come to a tight corner you go out wide then take it in a long arch or you will just spin out 9/10 times.
>
> ([source](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/wrecked-revenge-revisited/guide/))

Comment: Is it really luck? I want to do this because I immediately turn around with my car and drive backwards ;) With the start boost this is done much quicker.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a randomized start boost or just that sometimes someone will use the start boost they have after the race begins. Have you tried boosting right after the start of the race?

Comment: Yeah I did, but that is not the same ;) There must be a way because it happens sometimes.

Comment: It's not mentioned anywhere I have looked leading me to believe it is random in that case.

Comment: Alright, you'll get my bounty but I leave this answer as unanswered.